# How to get the integral value of an Enum member using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, boxing, unboxing

Consider the following Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Digit:
    UInt64
{
    None = 00 << 00,

    One = 01 << 00,
    Two = 01 << 01,
    Three = 01 << 02,
    // Etcetera...

    Other = UInt64.MaxValue - 1,
    Unknown = UInt64.MaxValue,
}

var type = typeof(Digit);
// Returns System.String [].
var names = Enum.GetNames(type);
// Returns System.Array.
var values = Enum.GetValues(type);
// Returns IEnumerable<object>.
var values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>();
```

Now, I want to get the numeric value of the Enum members without having to cast them to a specific integral type. This is for code generation purposes so below is an example of the code I want to be able to generate:

```
[Flags]
public enum Digit:
    UInt64
{
    None = 0,

    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 4,
    // Etcetera...

    Other = 18446744073709551614,
    Unknown = 18446744073709551615,
}
```

Of course, I could check the underlying type of the enumeration by calling `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);` and use conditional code to cast each case but was wondering if there is a more direct way.

Please note that I am just looking for the textual representation of the integral value and do not need to do any arithmetic with it or manipulation on it.

Am I missing something simple or is there no way to achieve this without casting?

Comment: I think you mean Three = 4...

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple `.ToString()` do the job here?

Comment: @TanveerBadar The problem is that the enum's ToString() will return the name (`One`, `Two` etc), not the numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this without some kind of conversion, but you can do it without having to use conditional code.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Digit :
        UInt64
    {
        None = 00 << 00,

        One   = 01 << 00,
        Two   = 01 << 01,
        Three = 01 << 02,
        // Etcetera...

        Other   = UInt64.MaxValue - 1,
        Unknown = UInt64.MaxValue,
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var type           = typeof(Digit);
        var values         = Enum.GetValues(type);
        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);

        var strings =
            values.Cast<object>()
            .Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, underlyingType).ToString())
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings));
    }
}
```

This outputs: `0, 1, 2, 4, 18446744073709551614, 18446744073709551615`

Comment: Thank you. Avoiding unnecessary branching is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am curious though as to why there isn't a more direct API in reflection for this.